# Native login page with IdentityServer4 authorization code flow

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I'm building a mobile application with Xamarin forms.
As part of the application i need to be able to authorize/authenticate users.
I am using IdentityServer4 and asp.net to achieve that.
From what i understand the recommended approach today is to use authorization code flow + PKCE.
There is only one problem with that, i don't want to redirect users to a login page on identityserver, i want the login page to be a native login page on the application.
How can i achieve that and still use authorization code flow?
Help would be appreciated.

Comment: That's simply not possible. The security of the flow depends on the login page code being a part of IDS, since the client can never be trusted. Why don't you use an embedded view?

Comment: Google doesn't allow web views from what i heard, it has a security risk.

Comment: Well, in the last project I was in with IDS4, we were going to use web views but the performance was just unbearable from a user perspective, ended up just launching the default navigator

Comment: The alternative to webview is ChromeCustomTabs for Android and Safari View Controller for IOS.